# merge files with bash by primary key

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, join

I have two files with with IP-Addresses as the primary key. File two has just a subset with different informations. I would like to add the 2nd column to the first file using bash.

file1:

```
192.168.1.1;hosta;aabbccddeef0
192.168.1.2;hostb;aabbccddeef1
192.168.1.3;hostc;aabbccddeef2
```

file2:

```
192.168.1.2;differentHostname;
```

My approach with for addr in `cat file2 | cut -d\; -f1; do grep -w $addr file1 ...` does not work, since I cannot access the hostname from file2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what `join` does:

```
$ join -a1 -t';' <(sort file1) <(sort file2)    
192.168.1.1;hosta;aabbccddeef0
192.168.1.2;hostb,aabbccddeef1;differentHostname;
192.168.1.3;hostc,aabbccddeef2
```

Note: `join` require files in sorted order.

You can specify the order of output using the `-o` option:

```
$ join -a1 -t';' -o 1.1 1.2 2.2 1.3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
192.168.1.1;hosta;;aabbccddeef0
192.168.1.2;hostb;differentHostname;aabbccddeef1
192.168.1.3;hostc;;aabbccddeef2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F";" -v OFS=";" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}($1 in a){$(NF+1)=a[$1]}1' file2 file1
```

tested:

```
> awk -F";" -v OFS=";" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}($1 in a){$(NF+1)=a[$1]}1' temp2 temp
192.168.1.1;hosta;aabbccddeef0
192.168.1.2;hostb;aabbccddeef1;differentHostname
192.168.1.3;hostc;aabbccddeef2
>
```