# Linux combine two different text files

Tags: python, linux, perl, awk, sed

I want to have one function like below using `awk`, `sed` or other tools.

1. Compare two files (File1, File2) with ID.
2. If same ID bring Same data from File2 to File1.

For example as below,

First File Name : File1.txt
Inside (Table format with tab delimited)

```
ID      Match     Length
100      OK        1000
200      OK        1000
300      OK        2000
400      OK        2000
500      OK        3000
```

Second File Name : File2.fasta
This information contained as below information

```
>100
ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG
>200
CTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGA
>300
TGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGAC
>400
GACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACT
>500
ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG
```

So I want to extend one more column to File1.txt file from File2.fasta
So here is final result

```
ID      Match     Length     Sequence
100      OK        1000     ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG
200      OK        1000     CTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGA
300      OK        2000     TGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGAC
400      OK        2000     GACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACT
500      OK        3000     ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG
```

Does anyone have any good ideas on how combine these two files?

Comment: I believe you're looking for join. Assuming you can format the fasta sequences to also use the same delimeter. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242791/merge-files-with-bash-by-primary-key

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer! I think almost close but only different first file delimited by \t but second file delimited by \n anyway thanks!

Comment: For completeness, I've added an answer that should take care of this for you. You just need it formatted first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for join, I believe.

First, you need your files sorted, and in a common format (same delimiter).

```
cat File2.fasta |sed 's/$/\t/g'|tr -d '\n' |sed 's/>/\n/g'|sort > File2.fasta.sorted
cat File1.txt|sort > File1.txt.sorted
```

Then, you just need join like this:

```
join -a1 -t'$TAB' File1.txt.sorted File2.fasta.sorted
```

Note here that $TAB is meant to mean the tab character.

This will produce something like this:

```
100 OK  1000    ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG    
200 OK  1000    CTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGA    
300 OK  2000    TGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGAC    
400 OK  2000    GACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACT    
500 OK  3000    ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG    
ID  Match   Length
```

Which is what you want (except for the column name/position).

Comment: Thank you for your answer I got error like join: join: multi-character tab `$TAB' Do you know what it is?

Comment: Yeah, $TAB was a placeholder. It should be replaced with a literal tab. '\t' won't work, but pressing control+v and then tab will. It'll look like ' ' in the terminal.

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46910/is-it-a-bug-for-join-with-t-t

Answer (score 0):

`IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && i=1 && for a in $(cat File1.txt); do ((i)) && echo "$a    Sequence" && i=0 || echo "$a     $(sed -n "/$(echo $a | awk '{print $1}')/{n;p}" File2.fasta)"; done && unset IFS`

Loops over the file and for the first line executes only once a new heading, after it uses sed to find the next line after the match and echoes it on the new column.