# comparing columns of multiple files using shell

Tags: sh

I have to compare two files based on first column, if they match then print second column of file1 and file2 in the same line

file 1

> 1cu2  pf00959
>   
> 3nnr    pf00440
>   
> 3nnr    pf13972
>   
> 2v89    pf13341
>   
> 4aqb    pf00431
>   
> 4aqb    pf00431
>   
> 4aqb    pf07645
>   
> 4aqb    pf00084
>   
> 2liv    pf13458
>   
> 2liv    pf01094

file 2

> 1cu2    d.2.1.3
>   
> 2v89    g.50.1.2
>   
> 2v89    g.50.1.2
>   
> 2liv    c.93.1.1
>   
> 2liv    c.93.1.1
>   
> 1q2w    b.47.1.4
>   
> 1q2w    b.47.1.4
>   
> 1rgh    d.1.1.2
>   
> 1rgh    d.1.1.2
>   
> 1zxl    c.2.1.2

output

> 1cu2  pf00959 d.2.1.3
>   
> 2v89    pf13341 g.50.1.2
>   
>  2liv  pf13458 c.93.1.1

Comment: So what's the question? What's not working in your code?

Comment: read about the `join` and `sort` commands. Sorry, Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service. Good luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [merge files with bash by primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242791/merge-files-with-bash-by-primary-key)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using more than Bourne (`/bin/sh`), you can do this in a one liner:

```
$ join <(sort -u file1) <(sort -u file2)
1cu2 pf00959 d.2.1.3
2liv pf01094 c.93.1.1
2liv pf13458 c.93.1.1
2v89 pf13341 g.50.1.2
```

If you're actually writing a shell script for `/bin/sh`, you'll need temporary files, e.g.

```
$ sort file1 > file1-sorted
$ sort file2 > file2-sorted
$ join file1-sorted file2-sorted
```

Update:  Your example output has one hit per key, even though 2liv has two values in file1.  To accomplish this, you need to run through a post-processor to note the duplicates:

```
$ join <(sort -u file1) <(sort -u file2) |awk '!done[$1,$3] { print; done[$1,$3] = 1 }'
1cu2 pf00959 d.2.1.3
2liv pf01094 c.93.1.1
2v89 pf13341 g.50.1.2
```

This uses a simple hash in awk.  The `sort -u` items already got rid of the duplicates from file1 (the second column of the final output), so we're merely looking for the first unique pairing of the keys with the values from file2 (the first and third columns).  If we find a new pair, the line is printed and the pair is saved so it won't print on its next hit.

Note that this is not sorted the way your sample output was.  That would be nontrivial (you'd need a third job just to determine the original order and then map things to it.)