# How to read 2 files same time in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a 2 input files say File1 and File2. File1 contains part of the record and remaining part of the record spread over to the File2, in order to create one record i need to read File1 and File2 same time. Each record's unique key will be there in the File1 and File2 before the record. Can you please help how to achieve this functionality using Spring-batch reader.

Comment: can you please explain better this phrase "Each record's unique key will be there in the File1 and File2 before the record"

Comment: To identify records spanned over to the File2 each record is having unique key which will there in each record in File1 and File2.                                    Example.ABCD123XXXXXXXX in File1                                                        ABCD123YYYYYYYYYYYY in File2                                                               ABCD123 is unique key to identify the record in both files

Comment: You may think about a shell tasklet to perform a file merge by key as first step (like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242791/merge-files-with-bash-by-primary-key) and next process it with SB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to start by loading each file to its own staging table in a relational database. Then just join the 2 staging tables together to insert to your final table.

Comment: Thanks Dean for your quick reply,  is there any other solution other than Staging table solution.

Comment: Not one that I'd recommend. You could sort each file by the business key and then transverse down each in a hacked reader, but it would not be a clean solution. Alternatively you could try joining the files with a shell script, but I personally would avoid having to split the solution between multiple applications.